# Return only columns containing NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data-frame:

```
i3<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
i2<-c(NA,1,1,1,2,2)
i1<-c(1,NA,2,4,5,3)
newdat1<-data.frame(i3,i2,i1)
print(newdat1)
  i3 i2 i1
1  1 NA  1
2  1  1 NA
3  1  1  2
4  1  1  4
5  2  2  5
6  2  2  3
```

I realize the solution for this is quite simple, but I am trying to return all the columns that any NA so that the final result looks like:

```
  i2 i1
1 NA  1
2  1 NA
3  1  2
4  1  4
5  2  5
6  2  3
```

I have found the following code which does the opposite:

```
newdat1<-newdat1[, sapply(newdat1, Negate(anyNA)), drop = FALSE]
```

But I cannot find exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: If it does the opposite of what you want, then you need to change the code to do the opposite of that. Remove Negate and leave anyNA.

Comment: @ARobertson This also worked thank you.

Comment: Btw, your own solution is the fastest by far.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you that is good to know.

Comment: Posted some benchmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `apply` and subsetting:

```
ind <- apply(newdat1, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) == 0 )

newdat1[!ind]
  i2 i1
1 NA  1
2  1 NA
3  1  2
4  1  4
5  2  5
6  2  3
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico do you mean within the `apply`?

Comment: sorry, I meant `colSums`; see my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
newdat1[!complete.cases(t(newdat1))]
```

Output:

```
  i2 i1
1 NA  1
2  1 NA
3  1  2
4  1  4
5  2  5
6  2  3
```

Comment: Very brilliant solution!

Comment: @SabDeM A stroke of luck. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So I just want to bring your attention that OPs solution is actually the best one (as I expected) because `apply` and `colSums` convert the whole `data.frame` to a `matrix`, while the other solution transposes the whole data set.

OPs own `sapply` solution works on vectors without transforming the whole data set while implementing a Primitive function, here are some benchmarks on a bigger data set

```
set.seed(123)
bidData <- as.data.frame(replicate(1e4, sample(c(NA, 1:3), 1e4, replace = TRUE)))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  mpalanco=bidData[,!complete.cases(t(bidData)), drop = FALSE],
  mikechir=bidData[,is.na(colSums(bidData)), drop = FALSE],
  sabddem =bidData[,!apply(bidData, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) == 0 ), drop = FALSE],
  OP = bidData[, sapply(bidData, anyNA), drop = FALSE])

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
# mpalanco 2347.0316 2401.32940 2434.24480 2421.22703 2449.32975 2972.82020   100
# mikechir  352.8597  363.01980  425.11366  403.58777  477.06792  799.15855   100
#  sabddem 1869.2324 2025.22459 2591.11786 2812.56430 2853.55268 3655.91325   100
#       OP   17.5455   18.25625   18.99749   18.65456   19.54728   25.36552   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base `R` and `colSums`:

```
newdat1[,is.na(colSums(newdat1))]

  i2 i1
1 NA  1
2  1 NA
3  1  2
4  1  4
5  2  5
6  2  3
```

Comment: My guess is that calling `as.matrix` explicitly within `colSums` will significantly speed up things

Comment: My solution is the slowest but I am wondering why the first two have these `max` values so high?

Comment: @DavidArenburg is that so? I included the benchmark because I thought it would basically scale up.

Comment: Actually all of these are inefficient because they need either to transpose or convert to a matrix the *whole* data set. For a big data set `newdat1[sapply(newdat1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))]` will almost surely the most efficient one