# Delete columns which contains NA in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I wish to get the tickers and delete those columns which contain any missing values. So I developed this for loop, but I am stuck as I get keeping errors such as see below. I am newbie to R, so I would appreciate if you can improve the for loop funtion below. Thank you:

```
    "Error in `==.default`(ETF_Adj_Data[columns], is.na(ETF_Adj_Data[,      columns])) : non-conformable arrays"
```

`install.packages("quantmod")`
`library(quantmod)`

```
sDate <- as.Date("2009-01-01")
eDate <- as.Date("2014-12-31")
ticker_symbol <- c("FLS","G4S","TDC")
ETF_Data <- new.env()
getSymbols(ticker_symbol, env=ETF_Data, from=sDate, to=eDate)
# Extract the Adjusted column from all objects,
# then merge all columns into one object
ETF_Adj_Data <- do.call(merge, eapply(ETF_Data, Ad))
# then extract the monthly endpoints
Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data <- ETF_Adj_Data[endpoints(ETF_Adj_Data,'months')]

for (columns in ncol(ETF_Adj_Data)){
if (ETF_Adj_Data[columns]==is.na(ETF_Adj_Data[,columns])) {
ETF_Adj_Data[columns] <- ETF_Adj_Data[,columns, drop=T]} 
else {
Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data[columns] <-         ETF_Adj_Data[endpoints(ETF_Adj_Data,'months')]
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(ETF_Adj_Data, function(x) if(!any(is.na(x)))  endpoints(x, 'months') )`

Comment: @Boro Dega I ran your code and all the three columns in `Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data`contain at least a NA value. You can check this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730990/return-only-columns-containing-na-in-r/31731474#31731474)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#delete columns
cok=apply(Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data,2,function(x)!any(is.na(x)))
Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data[,cok]  #empty

#delete rows
rok=apply(Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data,1,function(x)!any(is.na(x)))
Monthly_ETF_Adj_Data[rok,]
```

Comment: The row-wise case can also be done more simply with `complete.cases()` or `na.omit()` (if there are methods).

Comment: Thanks everyone. However, I was wondering whether you could modify my for loop function above..Thanks alot @RichardScriven